# magento 1.8.1. paypal suspected fraud

Tags: magento, paypal

We are having trouble with paypal. I know that there is an issue concerning magento and paypal and rounding the price. But there are so many workarounds and we are still having trouble with it. Now we would like to know if anybody has the same issue in version 1.8.1 and could solve the problem?

Comment: Same here and I'm still on 1.6, I've even encountered it at the checkout of Square Enix, not the smallest company around...